# @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn: Joining tables by primary key not working

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persistent

I have below two tables:

```
      `message` (
          `id` varchar(150),
          `Message` varchar(1000) ,
          PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
        ) 

fallback_status (
          message_key varchar(150),
          fallback_delivere` tinyint(1),
          fallback_read tinyint(1),
          fallback_answered tinyint(1),
          PRIMARY KEY (message_key)
        )
```

I don't have any foreign key relationship at database level. I have created two entity for these tables

```
@Entity
 @Table(name = "message")    
public class Message {

        @Id
        @Column(name = "id", unique = true)
        private String key;

        @Column(name = "message")
        String message

        @OneToOne
        @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "message_key")
        private MessageFallbackStatus messageFallbackStatus;

    }
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "fallback_status")
public class MessageFallbackStatus {

    @Id
    @Column(name="message_key")
    private String messageKey;
    @Column(name="fallback_delivered")
    private boolean fallbackDelivered;
    @Column(name="fallback_read")
    private boolean fallbackRead;
    @Column(name="fallback_answered")
    private boolean fallbackAnswered;
}
```

With this configuration Hibernate not able to persist data in fallback_status table. 
my questions are:

1. Is the foreign key relationship is mandatory at database level?
2. what would be the proper mapping for this scenario?

thanks for any help.

Comment: What's the code trying to persist a MessageFallbackStatus (which is completely independent of Message and its mapping, BTW), what do you expect it to do and what does it do instead?

Comment: I am creating a Message and setting  MessageFallbackStatus in it and then persisting message using sessionFactory.save(). it is only persisting data in message table not in fallback_table. I want it to persist data in both table.

Comment: You would need cascade=PERSIST on the association for that to work.

Comment: thanks @JBNizet. its worked.